# What is the difference between $x\times 0.8$ and $x \div 1.2 ? $

Tags: percentages

I came across this problem in a Khan Academy course:

> There are 20% percent more goblins than wizards in a magic club.
>   There are 120 goblins in the magic club.

To solve this problem I tried: $120 \times 0.8 = 96$. The correct answer was: $ 120\div 1.2 = 100$. What is the difference between $x\times 0.8$ and $x \div 1.2 
 ?$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lack of symmetry to these sorts of problems.

Saying that there are 20% more goblins than wizards is not the same thing as saying that there are 20% fewer wizards than goblins.

I it aproximatly true for small percentages, and the bigger the changes get, the farther they diverge.

There are 20% more goblins than wizards.... means we need some guess about the number of wizards.

$1.2\cdot \text {wizards} = \text{goblins}$

Then we are given the number of goblins.
and we can solve for the number of wizards.